# Extend Yii2's BaseYii class to add static methods

Tags: yii, yii2

Is it possible to extend Yii2's BaseYii class, so I could add a static method similar to `Yii::t()` like this: `Yii::my_super_method()`?

Can't really find any documentation about that, maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by creating own `Yii` class (for example in root of your project):

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php';

class Yii extends \yii\BaseYii
{
    public static function my_super_method() {
        // ...
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload'], true, true);
Yii::$classMap = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/classes.php';
Yii::$container = new yii\di\Container();
```

And loading it in `index.php` instead core class, by replacing:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
```

with

```
require __DIR__ . '/../Yii.php';
```

---

But if you want only to add a new method **you should probably not do this**. Overriding core classes in this way is possible, but this is ugly hack and should be avoided whenever possible. It is better to create own helper with this method than to hacking core classes.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was hoping Yii had created a way to do this but I guess logically this would be the only way and I agree it's hacky. Did not really know about writing helpers but I'll go have a read, maybe it will do exactly what I need

Comment: Helper is basically a class with public static methods, so it's not complicated at all.

Comment: strongly agree with the last part to create a helper class for such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to extend `BaseYii` class. show below

```
namespace app\models;

class ClassName extends \yii\BaseYii
{
     public static function my_super_method()
     {
         ......
         Here your code
         ........ 
     }
}
```

Now access your method like

```
app\models\ClassName::my_super_method();
```

Now access `t()` method

```
app\models\ClassName::t();
```

Comment: Well I know how to do that ;) but I'm wondering if it's possible to integrate these methods in Yii, to call them like such: Yii::custom_method(). Is there such a way, similar to components/modules config, to specify which class to use?